# Pass external values between chunks in clusterApply (parallel package)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a reproducible script to use a cluster. It is not optimized but used as a practical spiceman to study cluster application.

**The brief description of the task:**

1. There is a vector of a variable length;
2. It is required to transform it in specific manner:

   initial vector - 235416749...

   expected output- 235556779...

The transformation is performed with the application of the cluster (see the script below).

**The cluster output (sample)** is as follows:

> str(chunkSplit) #initial chunks
> List of 4
> $ : int [1:24950] 56583 22166 49905 20040 60870 49899 85589 96478 81119 36474
> $ : int [1:25050] 22652 31943 57699 58051 33846 27328 34429 84989 16295 29308
> $ : int [1:25050] 42641 69941 86274 86395 7499 62027 91978 55004 73069 1528
> $ : int [1:24950] 57401 60632 6284 43612 40011 31096 9494 24453 81221 99553
>
> str(cluster_Output) #updated chunks
> List of 4
> $ : int [1:24950] 56583 56583 56583 56583 60870 60870 85589 96478 96478 96478
> $ : int [1:25050] 22652 31943 57699 58051 58051 58051 58051 84989 84989 84989
> $ : int [1:25050] 42641 69941 86274 86395 86395 86395 91978 91978 91978 91978
> $ : int [1:24950] 57401 60632 60632 60632 60632 60632 60632 60632 81221 99553

The transformation inside of each chunk is in line with the logics described above.

**Process description**

The script expects to generate the overall output in correct manner (made of other chunks).
Thus, each next chunk must be transformed with the account of the transformation result of the previous one (the first element of the second chunk >= the last element of the first chunk).

However, chunks has not been transformed in this way.   Because the variable `max_val` does not transfer the proper value between chunks.

**Question:**
I guess it is because each worker generates own environment.
I would be very gratefull if you consult me how to solve the problen in the cluster (data transfer between chunks inside the cluster).

**Reproducible Script**

```
# Test cluster apllication
library(parallel)


# the function to be applied in the cluster
dochunks <- function(x) {
  
  # chunk counter
  step2 <<- step2 + 1
  xxx <- unlist(x)
  x_end <- length(xxx)
  
  # if it is the 2nd and higher chunks -> the 1st element of the vector
  # assigned as max_val
  if (max_val > xxx[1] & step2 >= 2) xxx[1] <- max_val
  
  i <- 1
  
  for (i in 1:x_end) {
    if ((i + 1) <= x_end & xxx[i] > xxx[i + 1]) {
      xxx[i + 1] <- xxx[i]
    }
  }
  
  max_val <<- xxx[x_end]
  return(xxx)
}


# the max value
size <- 100000
# test vector
myvector <- sample(100000, size, replace = TRUE)
# set up workers to process the vector
workers <- 4
# set up the cluster
cls <- makeCluster(workers)
# split test vector into chunks with the number of workers
chunkSplit <- clusterSplit(cls, myvector)

# max value of each chunk
max_val <<- 0
# temporary vector for each chunk
xxx <<- 0
# counter of the application of the each chunk
step2 <<- 0
# export vars into the cluster
clusterExport(cls, varlist = c("max_val", "step2"), envir = environment())
# run the cluster
cluster_Output <- clusterApply(cls, chunkSplit, dochunks)
# quit the cluster
stopCluster(cls)

# compare initial and updated chunks
str(chunkSplit) # initial chunks
str(cluster_Output) # output chunks
```

Comment: Here, you have at least two problems. Let me focus on only one: `max_val`. Basically, you use an updated value for `max_val` for other chunks? This means that you need to evaluate each chunk sequentially (you need chunk 1 to finish before using `max_val` in chunk 2), which means that this can't be parallelized.

If I didn't understand what you wanted to do, please make it clearer.

Comment: @F. Privé you are correct in your assumptions. 
It is pity i can not parallize it.

Comment: @F.Privé thanks for the hint